# How to treat coffeescript single values like arrays

Tags: coffeescript

I'd like to write some code that easily handles the input to be either a single value or an array and perform an operation on either the single value or each value in the array.

Ideally the code would just look like:

```
a = for i in j()
  i++
```

but j could return either 1 or [1, 2, 3].

I don't even see a good way to somehow check to see if j returns an array.  Maybe coffeescript has some good type identification system so I could do

```
if j().isArray then j() else [j()]
```

or something?

Anyone know of a syntactically appealing way of hiding this array conversion logic as much as possible?

Comment: You should cache j() in a var.

Comment: It looks like jQuery has an isArray method I could potentially use.  In this case that would be fine, but I'd prefer an answer that doesn't use jquery

Comment: @WTP that's generally good advice, but coffeescript takes care of that for you, `j()` won't be called multiple times.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
[].concat j()
```

will copy the result if array, wrap otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

```
asArray = (j) -> if j instanceof Array then j else [j]
```

Then call as

```
a = for i in asArray(j())
  i++
```

Comment: yeah, seems like that's about what I'm going to have to do.

Comment: `instanceof` does have some gotchas you should be aware of: http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/. If you need to, use the alternate isArray definition at the bottom of that page.

Comment: yeah, I'll probably use jquery's $.isArray: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/